# Data values not returning expected results

Tags: microsoft-band

I am having a few issues with the sensor data that is returned from the iOS SDK.  For calories, I am returning 86311 calories instead of 2708 that is displayed on my band.  Also, distance is supposed to be retuned as centimeters, but my values are inconsistent there as well.

For contact status, I do not even get results.

I'm not doing anything special other than using the "UpdatesToQueue" functions.

Has anyone else seen these issues?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 2):

The calories and distance returned by the SDK are totals since the band's last reset time. whereas the calories and distance displayed on the Band are daily values.

Comment: Interesting.  I did not see that anywhere in the documentation.  Thank you!  Have you seen anything about the contact status?  For me, it does not work at all.

Comment: Contact status updates are delivered only when the Band state changes (i.e.) user puts on the Band or takes it off.